# How Under local ubuntu 20.04 ro install nginx with Virtual Host Configs?

Tags: nginx

Under local ubuntu 20.04 I have appache2 installed and used and I want install nginx and
and to switch them on need.

I switch to nginx with commands :

```
sudo systemctl disable apache2 && sudo systemctl stop apache2
sudo systemctl enable nginx
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

to set 2 laravel apps using Virtual Host Configs.
I edited nginx.conf :

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


    gzip on;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

and 2 files for my sites
/etc/nginx/sites-available/Laravel9TestWithNginx.conf :

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /_wwwroot/lar/Laravel9TestWithNginx/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php;

    server_name   local-laravel9-test-with-nginx.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

and /etc/nginx/sites-available/AdsBackend8.conf:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /_wwwroot/lar/AdsBackend8/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php;

    server_name local-ads-backend8.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Also I Created 2 links with commands:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/Laravel9TestWithNginx.conf   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/AdsBackend8.conf   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

So I have :

```
root@hoster-os:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 20 16:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Apr 16 09:21 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   43 Apr 20 16:40 AdsBackend8.conf -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/AdsBackend8.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   53 Apr 20 16:40 Laravel9TestWithNginx.conf -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/Laravel9TestWithNginx.conf
```

In file /etc/hosts I have added lines:

```
192.168.55.164   local-laravel9-test-with-nginx.com
192.168.55.164   local-ads-backend8.com
```

I am not sure actually, is "192.168.55.164" nginx ip which I can use under ubuntu ?

I have empty /etc/nginx/conf.d/ subdirectory, as 2 config files are located in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ ...

But restarting the server :

```
systemctl restart nginx

systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-04-21 17:51:41 EEST; 57s ago
Docs: man:nginx(8)
Process: 32914 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; hoster_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 32915 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; hoster_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 32916 (nginx)
Tasks: 5 (limit: 9331)
Memory: 4.5M
CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
├─32916 nginx: hoster process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; hoster_process on;
├─32917 nginx: worker process
├─32918 nginx: worker process
├─32919 nginx: worker process
└─32920 nginx: worker process

Apr 21 17:51:41 hoster-os systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Apr 21 17:51:41 hoster-os systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

I and running sites in browsers I got error :

```
This site can’t be reachedlocal-laravel9-test-with-nginx.com took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

In my system I have :

```
ls /var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock
/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock
root@hoster-os:/# ps aux | grep php
root        1443  0.0  0.3 259144 31468 ?        Ss   15:27   0:00 php-fpm: hoster process (/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data    1610  0.0  0.1 259516 13956 ?        S    15:27   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data    1611  0.0  0.1 259516 13956 ?        S    15:27   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
systemd+    4275  0.0  0.1 203936 12032 ?        Ss   15:27   0:00 php -S [::]:8080 -t /var/www/html
hoster      9066  0.0  0.0   4864  1864 ?        S    15:28   0:00 /bin/sh /opt/PhpStorm-2021.1.4/PhpStorm-211.7628.25/bin/phpstorm.sh
hoster      9083 15.3 23.8 6936644 1918060 ?     SLl  15:28  22:16 /opt/PhpStorm-2021.1.4/PhpStorm-211.7628.25/jbr/bin/java -classpath /opt/PhpStorm-2021.1.4/PhpStorm-211.7628.25/lib/bootstrap.jar:/opt/PhpStorm-2021.1.4/PhpStorm-211.7628.25/lib/util.jar:/opt/PhpStorm-2021.1.4/PhpStorm-211.7628.25/lib/jdom.jar:/opt/PhpStorm-2021.1.4/PhpStorm-211.7628.25/lib/log4j.jar:/opt/PhpStorm-2021.1.4/PhpStorm-211.7628.25/lib/jna.jar -Xms128m -Xmx983m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Dsun.tools.attach.tmp.only=true -XX:ErrorFile=/home/hoster/java_error_in_phpstorm_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/hoster/java_error_in_phpstorm_.hprof -Didea.vendor.name=JetBrains -Didea.paths.selector=PhpStorm2021.1 -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/home/hoster/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2021.1/phpstorm64.vmoptions -Didea.platform.prefix=PhpStorm com.intellij.idea.Main
root       33159  0.0  0.0  11860  2744 pts/3    S+   17:54   0:00 grep --color=auto php
root@hoster-os:/# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
root@hoster-os:/# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-lUTckl/nginx-1.18.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-compat --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_gun



# sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

root@hoster-os:/# uname -a
Linux hoster-os 5.15.0-53-generic #59~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 15:10:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I did not find any errors under /var/log/nginx...

What is wrong in my config and how to run my site ?

Thanks in advance!